# Add php and nginx settings to homestead 2.0 provisioning

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, homestead

i would like to increase the default max-post size in the php.ini and max upload size in the nginx config. How can i add that in an .sh file so it get executed when i provision the box?

Answer (score 0):

Use the provision tools, such as puppet, chef, salt, ansible, etc.

For example, put below lines in your `Vagrantfile`, it will automatically apply puppet modules  (such as php and nginx) with your changes.

```
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = "modules"     
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "vagrant.pp"
    puppet.options = ['--verbose']
  end
```

Take a look on these urls.

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the exact question would be (given the current version of Homestead):

- After cloning go to src/stubs and edit the `after.sh` file
- launch `init.sh` from the root of the repository
- `vagrant up`

`after.sh` is a file copied to the VM and launched after homestead finishes its provisioning.